# Check comma seperated column value in range of values - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like below

```
Id    Col
----  ------
1      a
2      b
3      a,b
4      b,c
5      b,a
6      c
7      ab
```

I am looking for sql where the user select value 'a' or 'b' or both (it can bee any number of values like 'a', 'b' ) from frontend.

```
Declare @searchval varchar(max)
SET @Searchvalue = 'a'
    Select id from tbl where col in (@Searchvalue ) should return 1,3,5

SET @Searchvalue = 'a,b'
    select id from tbl where col in (@Searchvalue ) should return 1,2,3,4,5
```

above query is excluding row where searched data is together.

Comment: You should normalize your database table.  @GordonLinoff would agree with me.

Comment: It is the structure that is been running ...we need to work around thiss

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I agree, too - whole heartedly! When are all these self-proclaimed "database designers" finally going to stop putting **multiple values** into a single data cell, violating even the **first normal form** of relational design???

Comment: @marc_s Using CSV in a column totally undermines the power of the RDBMS.  Happy new year, by the way.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: same to you!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . I strongly agree with you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Everyone thanks for your contribution. I too acknowledge the DB design was not appropriate. I solved the issue by splitting the column value populate into a table variable and used it in my query

```
DECLARE @Prog TABLE
(
UserID INT,
Program VARCHAR(8000)
)
INSERT  @Prog
SELECT UserID,
LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]','varchar(8000)'))) AS Program
FROM
(
SELECT ID,CAST('<XMLRoot><RowData>' + REPLACE(col,',','</RowData><RowData>') + '</RowData></XMLRoot>' AS XML) AS x
FROM   tbl 
)t
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData')m(n)

Select * from @Prog where Program in (@SearchValue)
```

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, the right thing to do is to have a proper data structure for your lists.  SQL has a great data type for lists:  it is called a table, not a string.

Sometimes, you are stuck with other people's really bad decisions.  Probably the easiest way to construct the query you want is:

```
where ',' + col + ',' like '%,a,%' or
      ',' + col + ',' like '%,b,%'
```

If the values are actually single letters, then this can be simplified -- in fact, the commas don't really serve a purpose in that case.  You can just do:

```
where col like '%[ab]%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
 where col = 'a'
 or col like 'a,%'
 or col like '%,a,%'
 or col like '%,a'
 or col = 'b'
 or col like 'b,%'
 or col like '%,b,%'
 or col like '%,b'
```

Comment: my input value can be any number of vaalues

Comment: Then you have to build the sql on the fly, no matter what syntax you choose.

Answer (score 0):

It`s verbose but you can replace where with charindex

```
SELECT t.id FROM t
JOIN t tt ON CHARINDEX(',a,',CONCAT(',',t.col,','))>0                       
GROUP BY t.id
```

and second query

```
SELECT t.id FROM t
JOIN t tt ON CHARINDEX(',a,',CONCAT(',',t.col,','))>0 
                       OR CHARINDEX(',b,',CONCAT(',',t.col,','))>0
GROUP BY t.id
```

[FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d6e3d3/3)

Comment: it is not limited to 'a' or 'b', it can be any number of characters

Answer (score 0):

You have to split the search string into separate parts and then use that in your query...
Try this

```
CREATE TABLE #A(
    Id      int, 
    Col     varchar(10))

INSERT INTO #A
VALUES  (1, 'a'),
        (2, 'b'),
        (3, 'a,b'),
        (4, 'b,c'),
        (5, 'b,a'),
        (6, 'c'),
        (7, 'ab')

DECLARE @InExp  VARCHAR(255) = 'a,c',
        @Sep    VARCHAR(10) = ',';

--<Make sure there's at least one separator in the search string    
IF CHARINDEX(@Sep, @InExp) = 0     
    SET @InExp = @InExp + @Sep;

--Split the search string into parts
WITH data AS (
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@InExp, 1, CHARINDEX(@Sep, @InExp)-1) AS Chr, CHARINDEX(@Sep, @InExp) as Stop
    UNION ALL
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@InExp, Stop + 1, CHARINDEX(@sep, @InExp, Stop)-1) AS Chr, CHARINDEX(@sep, @InExp, Stop + 1)
    FROM data
    WHERE Stop > 0
)

--Join the parts on your table
SELECT DISTINCT a.*
FROM #A a
    JOIN data d ON CHARINDEX(d.Chr, a.Col) > 0

DROP TABLE #A;
```